# SSH Tunnel to a machine on another network

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel to a machine on a private network. I can `ssh` to one of the machines on the private network. My network is 10.4.0.x and the private network is 192.168.1.x.

I can `ssh` to the tunnel machine and then `ssh` to the destination machine from there without problems.

But I just want to tunnel from my machine directly to the destination. I am using this command but it is hanging. How do I specify the username of the machine I'm trying to access?

```
ssh -N -L localhost:22:DESTINATION_MACHINE:22 BRIDGE_MACHINE_USER@BRIDGE_MACHINE

ssh -N -L localhost:22:192.168.1.4:22 bridge@10.4.0.41
```

Comment: I infer that all of the relevant machines have an ssh server running on port 3306. Is that correct? Or do they have an ssh server running on the standard ssh port, 22?

Comment: No it is on the standard port 22

Comment: @Robᵩ How can you specify the username of the destination machine?

Comment: @Rob when I run the above command with sudo I can ssh onto the tunnel machine but then I get the error `could not request local forwarding`

Comment: You specify the username of the destination machine in the `ssh` command that connects to the destination machine -- which you haven't listed here. See my answer for complete discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps. The first command below sets up the port forwarding. The second command establishes an SSH session with the final destination machine.

#### First command:

```
ssh -N -L localhost:3306:destination:22 bridge-user@bridge-machine &
```

- `-N`: don't create an interactive login to bridge-machine, just connect and do the port forwarding.
- `-L localhost:3306:destination:22`. Arrange that any network request received on port 22 on the local machine is forwarded, via this ssh session, and re-issued on `bridge`. Since `bridge` can route to `destination`, the re-issued request will work. We choose `3306` because we need a port number that is not presently being used. We use `22` as the destination because that is the well-known port for SSH.
- `bridge-user@bridge-machine` - Since this SSH session terminates at `bridge`, we need `bridge` credentials.
- `&` - run in the background so that we can issue the second command.

#### Second command:

```
ssh destination-user@localhost -p 3306
```

- `destination-user` - Since the end-point of this connection is `destination`, we need credentials from there.
- `@localhost` - We are actually connecting to the forward service established in step 1.
- `-p 3306` - The command from step 1 arranged that any requests received on `localhost:3306` will be re-issued from `bridge` to `destination:22`. So we treat `localhost:3306` as a local alias for `destination:22`.

Comment: do I also have to supply the password to log onto the `bridge-machine`?

Comment: I am trying `ssh -N -L localhost:3306:192.168.1.4:22 bridge@10.4.0.41 &` and then `ssh test@localhost -p 3306` but it is saying connection refused.

Comment: Yes, you will have to supply whatever credentials are required to log into the bridge machine. That might be password or it might be an RSA public key, etc.

Comment: If the second command is printing `ssh: connect to host localhost port 3306: Connection refused`, then the first command did not succeed.

Comment: Thanks I got it working.